# Passing dynamic regexp via bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gawk

I'm coding a simple bash script to pass a IP port to a regexp to an awk command. I'm looking for the port only in the Local Destination

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
s=$1
port="/[^0-9]$s$/"
netstat -numeric | awk -v pat="$port" '$6 == "ESTABLISHED" && $4 ~ pat {print}'
```

Here is example of data.

```
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:54156 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.4:51376 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:53299 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:64695 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:53086 1.9.1.8:23   ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:53296 ESTABLISHED
```

When I run the script, it returns nothing.

When I run it manually , it returns the following:

```
netstat -numeric | awk '$6 == "ESTABLISHED" && $4 ~ /[^0-9]23$/ {print}'

tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:54156 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.4:51376 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:53299 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:64695 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0  1.9.1.1:23    1.9.2.1:53296 ESTABLISHED
```

Any suggestions would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
port="[^0-9]$s$"
```

You can remove the `{print}`, btw, as that's the default action, so all you need is:

```
s=$1
port="[^0-9]$s$"
netstat -numeric | awk -v pat="$port" '$6 == "ESTABLISHED" && $4 ~ pat'
```

The reason what you had didn't work is that `/.../` are regexp constant delimiters, like `"..."` are string constant delimiters so including them in a dynamic regexp would be like if you included the quotes in a string, e.g. `foo="\"stuff\""` instead of `foo="stuff"`, the "/"s become part of the regexp instead of delimiters for the regexp.

Comment: No, they are not implied, read what I said again. `/.../` are **delimiters for constant regexps**. You aren't using a constant regexp you are using a dynamic regexp and you are saving the regexp as a string in a variable and within a string a `/` is just a literal `/` character. In `/foo/` the `/`s are not part of the regexp, they are the delimiters around the regexp that define it as a regexp constant. You could use `"` delimiters instead (`$0 ~ "foo"`) but that would make the regexp a dynamic regexp.